# How does syntax highlighting affect the learning of a new programming language?

Tags: learning, language, reading, hci, color

What impact does syntax highlighting have on students' progress in learning a new programming language?

I'm looking for studies along the lines of the following hypothetical experiment, which involves two groups of students: one group would code in an editor performing poor to no syntax highlighting of the language in question...

[image]

...while the other group would code in an editor performing comparatively richer syntax highlighting.

[image]

Do you know of any such studies? Do you have otherwise relevant references? A quick Google search hasn't returned much...

Comment: Although it is not a direct answer, you may want to look at [Using Eye-Tracking to Understand Program Comprehension](http://www.ptidej.net/organisation/icpc09ws/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Human-computer interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human%E2%80%93computer_interaction) describes the creation of programs that use [colors effectively](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=http://pirun.ku.ac.th/~btun/pdf/color1.pdf&ei=fbfWUvG0HujF2AX5uIDQBg&usg=AFQjCNERkWOGPrcieARbn7uRjhSlMW4mNw&sig2=K1-npSa6RFrKYIt67NPNlg&bvm=bv.59378465,d.b2I). Here we are not discussing how effective the implementation of the HCI colors are, but instead are focusing on the [learned pair association](http://www.intropsych.com/ch06_memory/paired-associates_learning.html) and repetition of color training in the [psychology of learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology_of_learning) programming.

Learned pair [association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_%28psychology%29) is a way of memorizing information by associating it with another set of information. In the United States and many other countries, when driving, there is an association between [red traffic signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic-light_signalling_and_operation) and "stop." When people see the color red in a light or at a sign for a distance, they know to stop.

Repetition is the process of repeating the same association with and without exposure time delay until it becomes memorized.

Association with color reinforcements take advantage of the Stroop effect. After sufficient training the brain sees the color green and thinks "comment" or the color purple and thinks "text string":

> Such interference was explained by the automation of reading, where the mind automatically determines the semantic meaning of the word (it reads the word "red" and thinks of the color "red"), and then must intentionally check itself and identify instead the color of the word (the ink is a color other than red), a process that is not automatized.

-[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect)

[Other research](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/xlm/19/4/789/) has been done with more alternations of text type. Consistency seems to reinforce learning.

Answer (score 3):

[Charles Fletcher](http://www.psych.umn.edu/people/facultyprofile.php?UID=fletc002), one of my professors as an undergraduate, studies reading comprehension. He once mentioned a program **called** [LiveInk](http://www.liveink.com/index.php), which he **researches**. This program **is intended** to improve comprehension for ordinary English, not programming language, but I **don't see** why it **wouldn't work** for programming language as well, to some extent at least. It sometimes **introduces** color (especially with verbs, apparently), but mostly breaks sentences into separate lines with varying indentation, which **could be** a problem for programming I **suppose**, but if not, indentation **could** also **be** another useful trick. I **tried** using LiveInk to format my answer and give you a sense of how it works on a decent-sized batch of text. It used one color (maroon) on the words I **have** bolded here, but I **couldn't preserve** the indentation (at least, I'm not that good with HTML).

Check it out! [LiveInk's research page](http://www.liveink.com/research.php) might **give** you some better things to read than Google, depending on what search terms you **choose** with Google, of course.

**Edit:** This question may also be relevant: [Effect of words highlighting on reading comprehension](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/688/4086)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You may also *bee* (pun intended) interested in http://www.beelinereader.com

Comment: Definitely! You might be interested in [research on BeeLine Reader](http://nycdyslexiaresearch.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/is-beeline-reader-helpful-for-dyslexia/)! (Not that this link is particularly useful "research.")